# Simultaneous execution of camera and timer using multiprocessing and opencv:

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a system that is using a timer and a camera inside a multiprocessing. Basically what I am trying to do is doing something after the timer ends. I personally have used pipe() concept in it. It works but not efficiently. Because of the frame drop.Also it takes quite a while to start the camera. In order to remove the frame drop what should I make changes in my code? Should I use pipe() concept at all? Here, is my code:-

'''

```
    import multiprocessing
    import sys
    import time
    import cv2

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    def countdown_send_msg(t, conn):
       p = 1
       while t:
           mins, sec = divmod(t, 60)
           timer = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(mins, sec)
           print(timer, end = "\r")
           time.sleep(1)
           t -= 1
           conn.send(p)

       p = 0
       conn.send(p)
       conn.close()

   def recv_msg(conn):
       while 1:    
       q = conn.recv()
       if q != 1:
           print("Timer out.")
           sys.exit()

       success, img = cap.read()
       cv2.imshow("Webcam", img)
       cv2.waitKey(1)

    parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        multiprocessing.freeze_support()

        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = countdown_send_msg, args=(20, parent_conn))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = recv_msg, args=(child_conn, ))

        p1.start()
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

'''